# Verificar a diagonal de um índice específico

Tags: java, c, array, matriz

Eu queria saber como verificar a diagonal de um índice em especial, por exemplo, colocar 1 em todos os números das diagonais da linha 2, coluna 2

0 1 0 1

0 0 1 0

0 1 0 1

1 0 0 0

Comment: Qual é mesmo a tua pergunta? Mostra o que já fizeste ... e não mistures java com C!

Comment: Como se fosse um jogo de xadrez, onde a dama verifica suas diagonais se tem alguma peça que a ameace...

Comment: é interessante ver o código que ja tens, porque não sei se ajudo com java ou com c.

Comment: Eu não consegui nem começar, tudo deu errado, pode ser java ou C, qualquer um para me dar uma ideia

Comment: Antes de fazer uma pergunta é preciso tentar resolver o problema e postar o que já conseguiu.

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem um valor cujo índice seria [x][y], então as diagonais terão os indices [x-1][y-1], [x+1][y-1], [x-1][y+1] e [x+1][y+1], coloque isso dentro de um try... catch com um ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException para caso seja um indice que não exista (por exemplo, se verificar uma casa nos cantos, então só terá 1 ou 2 diagonais ao ivés das 4)

Answer (score 0):

**Acredito que é só percorrer a matriz verificando onde a linha é igual a coluna e colocar 1 nessas linhas.**

```
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
       for(j=1;<=n;j++){
          if( i == j){
               m[i][j] = 1;
           }
    }
   }
```

**Recomendo que você pesquise mais um pouco aqui pois acredito que tenha algo semelhante postado aqui já.**